# LinearLayout arrange items

Tags: android, xml

I have a problem with arrange items in a LinearLayout.
This is what I need:
[image]

But with my code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/new_hot_hastag"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:text="Hồ-Hoài-Anh"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/new_hot_hastag"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:text="Bàn-thắng"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/new_hot_hastag"
                android:text="Hà-Nội-mùa-thu-tháng-8"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

This is my result:

[image]

How do these items arrange automaticially depend on their width?

Thanks for your attention !

Answer (score 1):

You were adding all the three `textviews` in a single `LinearLayout` having `horizontal orientation`. That is why you were not getting the view required.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/new_hot_hastag"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:text="Hồ-Hoài-Anh"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/new_hot_hastag"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:text="Bàn-thắng"/>

        </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/new_hot_hastag"
                android:text="Hà-Nội-mùa-thu-tháng-8"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry because of a confusing question. But look through this "How do these items arrange automaticially depend on their width?". That means : If value of 3 textview are "a" "b" "c" then 3 textview are still on 1 row because of their small width.

Comment: you are using "wrap_content" for width of individual textview, hence the textview occupies the width depending on the width of the text. So it would be better for me to understand if you could tell me whether you want all textviews in one row or not.

Comment: if number of characters of 3 textviews are small then they will be on 1 row. if number of characters of 2 first textview are small and the last textview is large then 2 first textview will be on the first row and the 3rd textview will be on the 2nd row. It is available to implement?

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/one_tv"
    style="@style/new_hot_hastag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:text="Hồ-Hoài-Anh" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/two_tv"
    style="@style/new_hot_hastag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/one_tv"
    android:text="Bàn-thắng" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/three_tv"
    style="@style/new_hot_hastag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/one_tv"
    android:text="Hà-Nội-mùa-thu-tháng-8" />
```

> PS  android:text="Bàn-thắng"  should be like this: android:text="@string/two"

string.xml:
Bàn-thắng
Good luck!

Comment: Sorry because of a confusing question. But look through this "How do these items arrange automaticially depend on their width?". That means : If value of 3 textview are "a" "b" "c" then 3 textview are still on 1 row because of their small width.

Comment: Impossible.  The id three_tv is:  android:layout_below="@id/one_tv"    That means:  no mater the value of 3 textview,"Hà-Nội-mùa-thu-tháng-8" is below "Hồ-Hoài-Anh"

Comment: You did define (The id three_tv is: android:layout_below="@id/one_tv") by yourself but I didn't. That depends on the width of their characters.